# Alfresco digitale workspace localization issue

Tags: docker, localization, alfresco

I have installed Alfresco using docker images as explained in this [Angel Borrow's github repos](https://github.com/alfresco/alfresco-docker-installer). All goes fine.
But some translation key are not processed. On this image you can see that the translation key "LOGIN.LABEL.USERNAME" is not replaced by it' value.

[image]

There are several other issues like that on some popups in  ADW (Alfresco Digital Workspace) app.

What is the best way to fix that?

PS : The same localization issues also exist on alfresco cloud.

Answer (score 1):

The first think to check is if you have an adBlock extension activated on your browser page, if it's the case, disable adblock for Alfresco digitale workspace and reload.

You can debug error by using developer tools on your browser (**F12**)
in network you can see errors related to labels blocked and have more details.

O.

Comment: I disabled my adblockers. but this has no effect ! 
But when all work perfectly in new incognito windows ... so I'm very confused

Comment: use developer tools on your browser (F12) and show us network or console errors